# How to say “otherwise” in everyday conversations

Tags: word-usage, single-word-request

Looking for the German translation of *otherwise*, I can see there are a lot of possibilities: *ansonsten, anderenfalls, sonst, anderweitig, im Übrigen* and so on. Here’s a little example of the English usage I’m referring to.

> I hope the weather improves, *otherwise* I’ll have to stay at home
>   [I’m just providing a sample context, no translation needed]

Which German word/expression is better to use? I’m referring to the most commonly used — and informal — ones.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The three best possibilities to form your sentence are:

1. [Hauptsatz] …, **ansonsten** *Verb*  …
2. [Hauptsatz] …, **anderenfalls** *Verb* …
3. [Hauptsatz] …, **sonst** *Verb* …

Example:

> [I hoffe, dass sie mir helfen kann], **sonst/anderenfalls/ansonsten** schreibe ich dir.
>   [I hope she can help me], otherwise I’ll write you.

The other two expressions don’t fulfill your requirements.